# Не устанавливаются модули pip внутри контейнера

Tags: python, linux, django, docker, pip

Решил задеплоить тестовый проект и купил для этого vps сервер на ubuntu от reg ru.
при сборке контейнеров происходит ошибка пакетов pip внутри образа с питоном:

```
    > [backend 5/6] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt:
#0 15.76 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/asgiref/
#0 31.37 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/asgiref/
#0 47.48 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/asgiref/
#0 64.58 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/asgiref/
#0 83.69 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/asgiref/
#0 98.81 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement asgiref==3.7.2 (from versions: none)
#0 98.81 ERROR: No matching distribution found for asgiref==3.7.2
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
root@cv3598657:/home/var/www/test_repo# client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

сам код образа и docker-compose:

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine3.19

    WORKDIR /app
    COPY ./requirements.txt ./
    RUN pip install --upgrade pip
    RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
    COPY ./src ./src
```

.

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  backend:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./backend
    image: django-backend
    command:
      sh -c "cd ./src && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 config.wsgi"
    depends_on:
      - postgresql-db

  postgresql-db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:14.6-alpine
    env_file: ./postgresql-db/.pg-env

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Ну а руками зайти и написать - чё выплюнет?

Comment: @donRumata пробовал, заходил внутрь запущенного контейнера и пробовал вручную установить каждый пакет, выдавало тоже самое:

#0 15.76 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/asgiref/

Comment: а `ping -c 5 pypi.org` из контейнера работает?